# Limited API - call all results from it with do while loop

Tags: php, php-curl

Working with this EIA API with a limit of 5000 results at once. What I'm trying to do is to loop and when I reach 5000 results loop again until all results are fetched and put in an array.

This is what I have done so far but they are still 5000 on the page. Not the actual number since they are around 10k.

In any case I don't know how much will be `length` when I call it but it will be more than 5000 for sure.

```
$offset = 0; 
$length = 5000;
      
$allData = array();

$url = "https://api.eia.gov/v2/international/data/v2/data?api_key=xxxxxxxxxx&start=1960&sort[0][direction]=desc&offset=$offset&length=$length";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
                
do {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    $jsonData = curl_exec($ch);
    $response = json_decode($jsonData);
                    
    foreach($response->response->data as $row1){
        $urlData[] = $row1;
    }                
    $received = $response->total; // total number of results

    $offset = $received - $length;
    $allData = array_merge($allData, $urlData);  
    //$offset += $received;
                
} while ( $offset == $received );

curl_close($ch);
```

Update: result

```
stdClass Object
(
    [response] => stdClass Object
        (       
            [count query execution] => 0.029705004
            [total] => 9517
            [data]
               (
                      .....
               )
)
```

So the total should be `$response->response->total` but when I add it to the `while ( $response->response->total > 0 );` it **timed-out**

UPDATE 2: `var_dump($response)`

```
object(stdClass)#5003 (3) {
  ["response"]=>
  object(stdClass)#5002 (7) {
    float(2.6497E-5)
    ["count query execution"]=>
    float(0.037652072)
    ["total"]=>
    int(9517)
    ["data"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  ["request"]=>
      ["sort"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
          ["direction"]=>
          string(4) "desc"
        }
      }
      ["offset"]=>
      int(9517)
      ["length"]=>
      int(5000)
    }
  }
  ["apiVersion"]=>
  string(5) "2.0.2"
}
```

for some reason with this setup `["data"]=> array(0) ()` is empty but should not be. This is actual what is (should return) returning

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [count query execution] => 0.039096933
            [total] => 9517
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [year] => 2021
                            [Id] => 57
                            [Name] => name
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [year] => 2021
                            [Id] => 57
                            [Name] => name
                        )
                            ..........
                    [4999] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [year] => 2021
                            [Id] => 57
                            [Name] => name
                        )
        )      
)
```

Comment: I don't see you updating `$url` anywhere inside your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Just creating a URL template once doesn't update the variable values on it's changes. You will have to set them each time you update them.
- You will also have to loop till the total number of records fetched for a particular `offset` is `0` for the pagination limit of `5000` (which is your `$length`). See the below snippet with the changes needed written inside the comments.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
                
do {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.eia.gov/v2/international/data/v2/data?api_key=xxxxxxxxxx&start=1960&sort[0][direction]=desc&offset=$offset&length=$length"); #Change-1

    $jsonData = curl_exec($ch);
    $response = json_decode($jsonData);
            
    foreach($response->response->data as $row1){
        $allData[] = $row1; #Change-2 
    }

    $offset += count($response->response->data); // #Change-3

} while ( count($response->response->data) > 0 ); #Change-4

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explanation. Tried the snippet but something isn't okay because all I got is - Error 524 A timeout occurred

Comment: @S.I. Are the total records pretty huge?

Comment: In this particular category that I call they are a total of 10230. Not huge at all. Also, I have managed to fix the timeout error but still return 4999 rows only.

Comment: Seems like it's getting timed out because of the `#Change-4`. Can't find out why. If I dump `$response->total` after curl_close I got the correct number result. BTW `print_r($offset)` is equal to `$response->total`

Comment: @S.I. That is strange. If you don't mind, can you let me know what is the `$response->total` value for `https://api.eia.gov/v2/international/data/v2/data?api_key=xxxxxxxxxx&start=1960&sort[0][direction]=desc&offset=10230&length=5000`. I am saying because for `10230` rows and `5000` as the row limit per page, it should over within 4 calls at the maximum.

Comment: My mistake, they are a total of 9517. `$response->total` for `https://api.eia.gov/v2/international/data/v2/data?api_key=xxxxxxxxxx&start=1960&sort[0][direction]=desc&offset=9517&length=5000` is `9517`

Comment: @S.I. Ok, so which property returns the current no. of record fetched in `$response`? We would have to take that for calculations.

Comment: I have updated my question with part of the API return. The actual data is in `$response->response->data` while the total rows are in `$response->response->total`

Comment: @S.I. Thanks but this wasn't completely helpful. My above update(done on #3 and #4) in the code should work for you if `$response->response->data` is an array.

Comment: with the changed: `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` and on both count - `count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable`

Comment: What can I provide in order to clear it even more?

Comment: @S.I. Can you `var_dump($response);` and show what you get as an output in your question?

Comment: I have updated my question with `var_dump($response);` and what should return.

Comment: @S.I. Ok I just saw that. The error you mentioned is impossible then. The data array being empty is natural is since we have provided the offset as 9517 and there are no rows beyond that.

Comment: I'm accepting the answer because actually helps the question that I have raised - how to paginate and take all the results. The emptiness of the array is another problem that I'm going to work on. Thanks a lot for your time and help!

Comment: @S.I. Glad to help. I am pretty sure it should work as expected as I tested it on my machine with sample APIs and all went well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245846/discussion-between-nice-dev-and-s-i).